# HTML CSS to split an image in two halves (both with the overlay text) and place in different positions

Tags: html, css

[I want to split this image into half in mobile view and display each of these halves at upper left and bottom left respectively of the same div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHwtV.png)

[Rough idea how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rc9CF.png)

something into like this.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. On Stack Overflow, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more
research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hope this helps!!

```css
.slice{
    width:238px;
    height:544px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.slice img {
    position: absolute;
}

.right-half {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

.bottom {
  float:right;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div class="slice">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHwtV.png" /> 
</div>

<div class="slice bottom">
    <img class="right-half" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHwtV.png" /> 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! Stack Overflow is not a code writing service! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: It's very much easier to understand if you know the basics of CSS... if not I can't help it!!

Comment: Thank you so much.. this actually helps a lot. And for all the people putting in their opinion ..its my very first time with html and I had to get it done.. !! no harsh feeelings tho. Still Thank a lot to the community.